# How to reduce time allotted for a batch of HITs?

Tags: mechanicalturk

today I created a small batch of 20 categorization HITs with the name [Grammatical or Ungrammatical](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=2J2GSCWY2AOOXTQVBRFOPQSDNEN115)  using the web UI. Can you tell me the easiest way to manage this batch so that I can reduce its time allotted to 15 minutes from 1 hour and remove also remove the categorization of masters. This is a very simple task that's set to auto-approve within 1 hour, and I am fine with that. I just need to make it more lucrative for people to attempt this at the penny rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a new HITType with the relevant properties (reduced time and no masters qualification) and then perform a `ChangeHITTypeOfHIT` operation on all of the HITs in the batch.

API documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ChangeHITTypeOfHITOperation.html